# Android Bluetooth HID implementation on different OS

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-ndk, hid

Well, I believe this should be able to be implemented on the Android.

Recently, I found some Android developers created the Android remote controller(KB/MOUSE) app by

installing an app onto the server side(could be Windows or Mac or Linux) system and interact each other by bluetooth.

However, I believe it shouldnt be necessary to install an app onto host side if

we can take advantage of standard Bluetooth HID profile.

I have implemented the Android Bluetooth HID application which can make your android device play as a bluetooth kb/mouse input device.

to control my Ubuntu without installing any host side daemon.

The engineering approach involves Bluez deeply so it doesnt work on Mac or Windows.

Please bear my lack of bluetooth knowledge. I am really curious about the possibility of this matter.

If any of you has any approach or idea about this, please kindly share.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, it seems this question is not yet implemented by the developer.

However, if any of you is interested in how to do this for Linux system. Feel free to write me an email. I would be happy to share the skill.

Comment: SamLin ... I would like to take you up on your offer and learn how to do this for a Linux system.  But, I do not have your email address...

Comment: Can you drop me a message to my stackoverflow message box with your email and I will mail you after seeing it?

Comment: I am not sure how to get to your "stackoverflow message box"; I do not see any such thing on your stackoverflow profile page. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ Karthik... I wrote you an email from my mail box. let me know if you receive it.

Comment: @Sam are you able to implement this ? Means are you able to make HID connection from android phone to bluez ?

Comment: @KalpeshLakhani yes, i was able to do it long time ago. I can use my cell phone (android) to connect to my laptop ( linux os ) to send the comment.